# Retain Column Order in Database Connector in Mule

Tags: database, mule, linkedhashmap

How can i force the database connector to return LinkedHashMap to ensure that resultset is in same order as in db?

Answer (score 1):

Though the DB resultset is unordered, we can still extract data from columns or map columns to the target we desire. So may i know in which scenario you're expecting the ordered resultset?
and the another question which struck me after seeing your question was, why the resultset is unordered in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

@vijay dhanakodi The best way would be to use data weave once you get the result and that arrange it accordingly example

%dw 1.0

### %output application/java

{
    firstColumn: payload.keyName as :object {class:"java.util.LinkedHashMap"}

}

Answer (score 0):

SQL drivers do not maintain or guarantee the order of columns in returned resultset. Why is order important? I had similar situation, see [this question.](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/40848/retain-column-order-in-database-select-resultset.html)